# consistent-return for useEffect

Tags: reactjs, eslint

When i do something like this

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (steps.step2 && !requestKey) {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => startProcess(), 500)
      return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
  }, [steps, requestKey, startProcess])
```

eslint complains me  `error  Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function  consistent-return`
for `return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)`

Because when i comment this an error disappears.

```
// return () => { clearTimeout(timeoutId); }
```

How to solve this, any ideas?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Nope, but I changed my code which occurs an error

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're returning in at least one branch, you need to always return a value to follow the rule. It doesn't have to be a function, it just has to be something other than the standalone statement `return`. This works too:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (steps.step2 && !requestKey) {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => startProcess(), 500)
      return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
    return undefined;
  }, [steps, requestKey, startProcess])
```

Also note that `setTimeout(() => startProcess(), 500)` simplifies to `setTimeout(startProcess, 500)`.

Comment: Seems returning `undefined` is better than function

Comment: ESLing should learn that a single `return;` in an untyped function will always return `undefined` which means that `return;` is exactly the same thing as `return undefined;`, both will return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

When i add this `return () => {}` at the end of useEffect(() => {...})

Now eslint doesn't complains about this.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (steps.step2 && !requestKey) {
      const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => startProcess(), 500)
      return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    }
    + return () => {}
  }, [steps, requestKey, startProcess])
```

Comment: Returning an empty function is unnecessary to resolve this linter error. As @CertainPerformance's answer states, you can `return undefined` instead.