# How to fix "Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function." error?

Tags: reactjs

Eslint is giving me the Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function error. How do I fix this?

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (show && inView) {
        const timer = () => {
            setCount(count + 1);
        };
        if (count >= number) {
            const plus = setPlus('+');
            return plus;
        }
        const interval = setInterval(timer, 800 / number);
        return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
    setCount(1);
    setPlus('');
    setShow(false);
}, [count, inView, number, plus, show]);
```

Comment: Are you lookin for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64886804/16698727)?

Answer (score 0):

do you use some react extensions for eslint in your project ?

Here's a standard eslint config for react projects:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
    ecmaVersion: 12,
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
    'prefer-arrow',
  ],
}
```

Try it in your .eslintrc and tell me if you still got this error

EDIT:

Can you join your eslint config file ?
You shouldn't get this error. Maybe I can explain you some stuff about it.
Or your can just disable this rule for your project by editing your .eslintrc file and adding:

```js
rules: {
    'consistent-return': 'off',
}
```

Comment: I tried disabling the rule and the code works, but I would like to find a solution rather than working around the problem if it is possible.

Comment: Then I think it's because you use a return in your if statement and not outside. Try to add a return (maybe an empty function), it should remove the error

Answer (score 0):

This is my .eslintrc

```
{
"env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
},
"extends": [
    "react-app",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended"
],
"parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module"
},
"plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
"rules": {
    "react/jsx-uses-react": ["off"],
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": ["off"],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": ["warn"],
    "no-shadow": "off"
}
```

}